# Is my integer significant?

Tags: code-golf, number

Your task is to write a function that takes an even-digit integer and compares the 2 halves of the integer. If the sum of the digits in the first half is greater than the sum of the digits in the second half, output a truthy value, otherwise, output falsey.

For example:

```
12345678
1234 5678
(1+2+3+4)>(5+6+7+8)
10>26

Output falsey
```

#### Input

A single integer.

- This must be passed as a single whole integer in base 10, a single string, an array of integers, or an array of characters. Please specify which format your answer accepts
- The input can be passed via Command Line Arguments, STDIN, or any other standard method of input supported by your language
- Assume the input will always have an even digit count
- Assume the input will always be positive and greater than 0
- Assume the input will be within feasible number handling capacities for your language
- The input will not contain leading zeroes

#### Output

A truthy value if the sum of the digits in the first half is greater than the sum of the digits in the second half.

A falsey value if the sum of the digits in the first half is less than **or equal** to the sum of the digits in the second half.

#### Test cases

```
Input > Output

12345678 > False
87654321 > True
12344321 > False
12 > False
214758392639543385 > False
1001 > False
100000 > True
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins.

Comment: The "duplicate" is an = check, this is a > check. I don't think they're duplicates.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because even though the differences are small, they obviously make a large difference given that answers to this are often 15-20 bytes smaller than the :duplicate".

Comment: I am reopening this challenge because the difference between > and = is not too major, but the guarantee of an even length integer changes the entire approach that a lot of answers use (not just removing one or two bytes).

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ḍ+ᵐ>₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wR6/2w60T7B41Nf7/b2hkbGJqZm4BAA)

### How it works

```
ḍ+ᵐ>₁                     example input: 12345678
ḍ        split in half                   [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
 +ᵐ      sum each half                   [10,26]
   >₁    results in a decreasing list    false
```

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, <s>39</s> <s>35</s> 28 bytes

```
@(x)sum(x)/2<sum(x(1:end/2))
```

Input integers as a string `'12345678'`.

Takes the `sum` of all the digits (as ASCII-values), and divides it by two, to get the mean of the two sides. Compares this to the sum of the first half of the integer, to check if it's smaller or not.

Comment: I like the use of ASCII values and calculating the mean, always cool to see different approaches to the task.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 34 bytes

```
\d
$*1;
+`;(.*);(.)
$1$2
1(1*);\1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LYnBDcAgDAP/mYNKQKWqTggEMUCX4MGj@69AQaoflu98@GfM/pKLaHSO5q8YVgVycEzwWNjR5gRL0lyMrGRNwqBt/kGMVNSkcpa6XjHdFvfOBw) Works by inserting `;`s after each digit as they are converted to unary. The `;`s are then deleted in pairs until only the middle and final `;`s remain and the numbers can then be compared.

Comment: How does it only remove the first and last semicolons each iteration?

Comment: The `*` in `.*` is maximal matching (greedy), so it would match as much as possible.

Comment: @KritixiLithos `*` is greedy, so it skips as many `;`s as possible.

Answer (score 5):

## Regex, 226 bytes

```
^(9(){9}|8(?<2>){8}|7(?<2>){7}|6(?<2>){6}|5(?<2>){5}|4(?<2>){4}|3(?<2>){3}|2(?<2>){2}|1(?<2>)|0)+(?<-1>9(?<-2>){9}|8(?<-2>){8}|7(?<-2>){7}|6(?<-2>){6}|5(?<-2>){5}|4(?<-2>){4}|3(?<-2>){3}|2(?<-2>){2}|1(?<-2>)|0)+(?<-2>)(?(1)^)$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#Tc1LCgMxCIDh/ZyjhYQijJonlJllbzH0HqNnTxPqQjd@6OJ/hs93XKGHeHeVFs43HfFuKtVYVYqxqGRjVknGpMJGViEjqeCfssfXFODR11pPK4FLgWuBi4GrgcuB64ELgitOhjNgvOJjDCROudS2tVpyYsJtXQwbYaq5cafCfX655XXFfc0P) (uses Retina to check)

Comment: I assume the 0 or 1 output is the number of matches? Meaning this will only match "significant" numbers? That's pretty cool.

Comment: What does the `(?<number>)` do?

Comment: They are called balancing groups. Please refer to [an answer written by Martin Ender on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/6211883).

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
g(h:t)=h-g(reverse t)
g _=0
(>0).g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bU3NCsIwDL73KXLw0EKUdbXrFOqLlCIDu26H/VCLr1/DhuLBBJLw/eQrkQ/XLOxwjDyFV0jPAFmwCHdbsd7yWyVOsUzdOIOFx8KAak3jnOEAU7dCD861aLBBjWdUWKP06CRWn/b@r0eSUpFDk9Ngu3l25PdLTZNuwgwpW2IuxDXb3vMUofqbKL0vbw) Take list as input.

Computes the sum of the first half minus that of the second half by recursively taking the first element and subtracting the recursive result on the reverse. For example:

```hs
g [1,2,3,4]    =
1-g[4,3,2]     =
1-(4-g[2,3])   =
1-(4-(2-g[3])) =
1-(4-(2-3))    =
1-4+2-3        =
(1+2)-(3+4)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>60</s> 40 bytes

*Saved some bytes thanks to @MartinEnder*

```
^(.)+?(?=(?<-1>.)+$)
$&;
\d
$*
.(1*);\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LYlLDoAgDAX3PQeagpFYyjeoLL0EMS68/xUQEt9qZt6E19Nu1HIpWA4s@0pnFyFBzBnqC0KBRlIyVxKtkWHrfIgQg3eWDcEoP4AhG1zkZDyn/nJ0o9I29gE)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
2äO`›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymrDP5vdHiJf8Kjhl3/K5UO77dSOLxfSee/oZGxiamZuQWXhbmZqYmxkSEXSATK4DIyNDE3tTC2NDIztgTKGluYchkaGBiCCCAAAA)

**Explanation**

Takes input as list of digits.

```
2ä     # split in half
  O    # sum each part
   `›  # is the first half greater than the second
```

To take input as an integer you could just add `S` for

```
S2äO`›
```

Comment: Oh, we're even now...

Comment: @LeakyNun: I like yours better though, due to the input format.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>68</s> 62 bytes

```
i=input()
print(sum(map(int,i))>2*sum(map(int,i[len(i)//2:])))
```

#### Short explanation:

- `input()` reads a string from `stdin`.
- `i[len(i)//2:]` takes the second half of the string.
- The `map` functions turn the string to an integer list.
- `sum`, `>`, `*2` and `print` do what they say.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> <s>62</s> <s>44</s> 35 bytes

<sub>Crossed out 44 is still regular 44. :c</sub>

*-16 bytes thanks to LeakyNun. -18 bytes on allowance of integer array input. -9 bytes thanks to Dennis.*

Takes input as an array of integers and returns True/False. Note that it relies on Python 2's integer division.

```python
lambda s:sum(s[:len(s)/2])*2>sum(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmqtRHG2Vk5qnUaypbxSrqWVkBxbT/F9QlJlXopGmEW2oo2Cko2Cso2Cio2Cqo2Cmo2Cuo2ARq6nJBVdiARYzA8ubgNUCdRiiKEE2BY8SFAGQCrBqc7DJFmBtlmCdZjA23EZjsAJTdBMNYMgQpwwIASX/AwA)

#### Explanation:

*I know this (or anything in Python) doesn't need an explanation but I'm doing it anyways for good practise. :P*

```python
    s[:len(s)/2]             # Gets first half of array
sum(s[:len(s)/2])            # Calculates the sum of the values
sum(s[:len(s)/2])*2          # Multiplies it by 2 (explanations...)
                    sum(s)   # Total sum of the digits
sum(s[:len(s)/2])*2>sum(s)   # Compares the two sums
```

Comment: [Golfed](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmquRm1igkZlXolMcbZWTmqdRrKlvFKupaYcqBZOxAkr9LygCCmqkaagbGhmbmJqZW6hranLBBS3MzUxNjI0MUQRBKrEIonCNDE3MTS2MLY3MjC2BJhhbmKJIG4AAmgFgMaDQfwA)

Comment: @LeakyNun I should really learn how `map()` works. o0 Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the sum of both halves is the total.

Comment: @Dennis I hope [this](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFVcmqtRHG2Vk5qnUaypbxSrqWVkBxbT/F9QlJlXopGmEW2oo2Cko2Cso2Cio2Cqo2Cmo2Cuo2ARq6nJBVdiARYzA8ubgNUCdRiiKEE2BY8SFAGQCrBqc7DJFmBtlmCdZjA23EZjsAJTdBMNYMgQpwwIASX/AwA) is what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 52 Bytes thanks to help in comments

```
lambda x:sum(x[i]-x[~i] for i in range(len(x)//2))>0
```

The idea was to substract the first digit from the last, second from second last... and check if the sum of all substractions is greater then 0.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#fY3NCsIwEITvPsUeE9hi098o6IvEHCK2EmhTiQp5@9iutFhBYQ7LzDez7eEUO9OfLwbC/v7smQrK6iSornEs8MQmQreDBwvWgTfu2rB3ss245sc03rx1D9YyJRAyhByhQCgRKoQaQWrONwsiyasoL4gdG2KFfK78QVbGRBBd07Kk2o6a1XwvH3MCyu/FdJb4mUwaw/gC)

Comment: Can you use string indexes?

Comment: @erbsenhirn use `x[i]-x[~i]` for the same output. you can index python `list`s with negative indices, `-1` being the last, so `x[-i-1]` would do the trick, but `-i-1 == ~i` :D

Comment: @erbsenhirn you can remove `[` `]` from the `sum`, as: `sum(x[i]....range(len(x)/2))>0`

Comment: Nice approach, but it doesn't beat [doing it the regular way](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119121/68615).

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 54 bytes

```php
for($n=$argn;~$n[2*$i];)$s+=$n[$i]-$n[-++$i];echo$s>0;
```

takes input from STDIN; empty output for falsy. Requires PHP 7.1. Run with `-nR`.

**breakdown**

```php
for($n=$argn;       # import input
    ~$n[2*$i];      # loop while there is a 2*$i-th digit (0-indexed)
)
    $s+=$n[$i]          # 1. add $i-th digit
        -$n[-++$i];     # 2. subtract -1-$i-th digit
echo$s>0;           # if $s>0, print "1" , else print nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
2,╡♂Σi>
```

Input is taken as a list of digits. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2@k82jqwkczm84tzrT7/z/aUMdIx1jHRMdUx0zHXMciFgA)

Explanation:

```
2,╡♂Σi>
2,╡      split input into two equal sublists
   ♂Σ    sum each sublist
     i>  is first sum greater than second sum?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
œs2S€>/
```

Saved a byte by changing the input to a list of digits.

Saved several more thanks to Leaky Nun!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AR4A4f//RMWTczJT4oKswrXhuKI84bmq////NTY3ODEyMzQ)

Explanation:

```
œs2    Split that list into 2 chunks
   S€  Sum each chunk individually
>/     Reduce the resulting list by relative compare.

Prepend this to work with integer input instead of a list:

D       Turn the integer into a list of digits
```

Comment: You can remove 2 bytes with the latest version of Jelly: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJI9Dy@30/7scbn/UtOb/f0MjYxNTM3MLHQULczNTE2MjQwA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 79  or 75, 74

better version (80 char -> 79 thanks to titus )

```c
f(char*s){int i=0,n=strlen(s--)/2;for(;*(++s+n);)i-=*s-s[n];putchar(48+(i<0));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#VYzLCoMwFET3foW4utcYzFMjqV9SupBSaaBNi7Er8dttUuhrVucwzGwjHM/DVAZcnJ9z17PK92GeLicPgVKshR1vE9gSCAnEo0VH@zLQsPcHe3/MaQzKEHA7hmjXLb1cB@cBsyXLRyi4kEo3rSnQvty0jVZS8Len/t8T1XVkVrGq@DaCq1Yb2YlGdvFCGv3ZMMZ/OCbZuj0B)

next, 75 bytes if we rely on constant undefined behaviour,

```c
f(char*s){int i=0,n=strlen(s)/2;for(;s[n];)i-=*s-s++[n];putchar(48+(i<0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#VYzLCoMwFET3foW4utcYzFMjqV9SupBSaaBNi7Er8dttUuhrVucwzGwjHM/DVAZcnJ9z17PK92GeLicPgVKshR1vE9gSCAnEo0VH@zLQsPcHe3/MaQzKEHA7hmjXLb1cB@cBsyXLRyi4kEo3rSnQvty0jVZS8Len/t8T1XVkVrGq@DaCq1Yb2YlGdvFCGv3ZMMZ/OCbZuj0B)

input valid string in C (a zero terminated array of char)
output 1 for true, 0 for false

ungolfed version

```c
f(char*s)
{
    int i=0;
    int n=strlen(s)/2; /* n is the length of each strings  so we have 
                          the start of the first string at *s or s[0],
                          and the start of the second sequence at s[n] 
                        */
    for(;s[n];) /* until we get 0, all string in C are terminated by 0 */
        i-=*s-s++[n]; /* i is the difference between the two characters *s and s[n], 
        then we move the cursor to the next character (s++) :) 
        on the string 12345678, after the first iteration we have 
        i == -4 and 234,678 the proceed
        */
    putchar(48+(i<0)); /* put char '0' if i<0, char '0'+1 otherwise (the char '1')
 }
```

and now 74 thanks to "a stone arachnid"

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 74 bytes

```c
f(char*s){int i=0,n=strlen(s)/2;for(;s[n];)i-=*s-s++[n];printf("%d",i<0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxLDoMgFEXnrsKQNAHFyEcUQ11J04Gh1ZK0tAFnxrVTaNLfG92Tc9/V1ax1CBPUl9EVHq3GLrkZCLaDX9z1bKFHNVPT3UHlD/aokKmGwle@LBM9XOxPEOxOAJs9QWoLaeA2GgtRtmZ5dJTxRrSdBEi9WHataDijb07@n1Oq65gJJhh8DaNNJyTvWcv7OMGl@PwQQn9yvERbeAI)

Comment: `i-=*s-s++[n];` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Would `48+(i<0)` work?

Comment: `printf("%d",i<0)` is shorter than `putchar(48+(i<0))`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxLDoMgFEXnrsKQNAHFyEcUQ11J04Gh1ZK0tAFnxrVTaNLfG92Tc9/V1ax1CBPUl9EVHq3GLrkZCLaDX9z1bKFHNVPT3UHlD/aokKmGwle@LBM9XOxPEOxOAJs9QWoLaeA2GgtRtmZ5dJTxRrSdBEi9WHataDijb07@n1Oq65gJJhh8DaNNJyTvWcv7OMGl@PwQQn9yvERbeAI "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```js
f=([n,...a],d=0)=>1/n?f(a,d-=n-=a.pop()):d<0
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=this.value.length%2?``:f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Takes input as a string or array of digits as characters or integers.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 148 bytes

```
void q(){var a=Console.ReadLine();int b=0,c=0,i=0,d=a.Length/2;for(;i<d;i++){b+=int.Parse(a[i]+"");c+=int.Parse(a[i+d]+"");}Console.WriteLine(b>c);}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
F<mΣ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/qKkx5b@bTe65xYf2/v//39DI2MTUzNwCAA)

Input as an array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 13 bytes

```
.,2//{{+}*}/>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0/HSF@/ulq7VqtW3@7/f0MjYxNTM3MLAA)

```
.,              # Get the length of the input                        "12345678" 8
  2/            # Half it                                            "12345678" 4
    /           # Divide the string in groups of that many digits    ["1234" "5678"]
     {    }/    # For each string
      {+}*      # Add the ascii values                               202 218
            >   # Is the first bigger than the second?               0
```

It actually adds the ascii values of the numbers, but both groups of digits have `d` digits, so both results are `48*d` more than the actual value. This would only be a problem if the groups had different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>8</sup></s> <s><sup>7</sup></s> 6 bytes

*Thanks to @Razetime for saving 1 byte due to the `⌊` command auto-vectorising.*

```
½⌊v∑>t
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%BD%E2%8C%8Av%E2%88%91%3Et&inputs=%2212345678%22&header=&footer=)

Takes input in the form of `"12345678"`. Alternatively, the quotes can be left out if the `Ṡ` flag is used.

I’m gonna be honest, I’m not really sure what the `>` is doing since `(a:string, b:list)` isn’t documented for that command, but I was messing with it and found that in this case it returns `<1|0>` or `<1|1>`, so I take the last value of the list and that’s the answer.

Explanation:

```
        # Implicit input
½       # Split the input into two chunks
 ⌊      # Convert both chunks to integers
  v∑    # Sum the digits of each chunk
    >   # Some sort of a>b thing?
     t  # Tail; last item
        # Implicit output
```

Comment: `v⌊` -> `⌊` since it auto vectorizes

Comment: @Razetime Added. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Very clever usage of `ḭ`. +1

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 20 bytes

```
dl2/2->[+]>l3->[+],-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#xVlLc9s2EL7rVyBuU5GNpEh2TpLtdqaTzPTUHjq9KKqHIUEJDU2yAOnY007/ursLgHiQkCxNpvbFFheLfXz7ILB8zHl1S8SDIOy2rnhDEr69W40kNW/LtKmqwqxxmrUp1atpVRQ0bVhVmvWM/tXCsn6qxKxOmp19rilPmoobAmsol/JXo1FaJEIQISVE8m@8HBGQmJObmy1tgPf25iYStMgnhJUZvZfrhLCcMMFK0SRlSiO5MiGiYCnVDATMblpekuahplJAHBnNMyZZXbkzEMUb@1DV9jet43jkiJSGzvYZOBqh@WhdEwlpTcMftNWS5Ir6jbcUnul9SuuG/J4ULX3PecWXLtOHpBBUiVVo0qhDdUJyxgXYLWhalZlUp3d1LJHPsVKCwHbwOP18lxSR/DEhNaeC8js6AQl3UhKg3BE9g@SG9XyDDMBLKNinidPFZoUOAWW4ZVZXdUHzJoqHO3EtClgnDppX0FKtx@SaLExu@FYTgkrJ1RF2S4vZdme5F0Huc81t/fSVHONpQNtx26zS/a76Tsz3mzvQr3TosEXINVFMXXDqhAsapVWmaq3mmNbjX4HKyi15LcbkNZGrKEeKRfGqxiVNxw17DobtQlmkON9cyV60vlhuVoEQzxWv1vlzWbfNUqtcI4nFJK84YVBqWiB2io2CrczAEFlMK2m3As6lQYXcQY9wSRAECv66JNFw9NShUJEmtcdz2xYNk2Z6Oz@z2n1muWeSYOCstyEv5AZsE/hYVJW3f8spzR5cCnLIVgbE@aoLT1q1Uu7ZmbEt3SXcUO477i87MAEeLyXsJsaADHDg4/pep9I9hmoBKYEPiPkDYs6Tckuj@cQGzfRjCIRKxgeoKEHKqsF@2K0Su3il@qR@jLUK3A7oOdLApCsy/mdMQLn6vRw74npQd9uyPhFi3rAS8e30IIYDPRtHtnEFWonJSdcLoE8lOnYBITbBsQtuRcqq7EXYk2vbg10amm9Tz3FCvY/S2OpyEgMimYYkhkzsUgnFWRGxakVGomxbCxd3GXCV4K6/upLHsz8rVkbrdMcjJu2FFFwsFu8Wi3MlbN6v7LXNsalUutxs4glW@dV4HA9U9/ukbTldk1z2BW6skHA5dy4MG4mWP6jnAfSqAk2Gy84yyL2zMUmgeaEbqtO4VdPvRa5rENh1xTOvLZrq77vndQQVeGPBx49@@odMcdpg16@G6WM12aRTelTr7ThVvid1DfGM0IU0jp2K7Xdpz9ilhQvq3Uj87LVSb8fZ2OrVeAb5bsZObFC@asDLY/P8qVMXvmlCOXxqivmY@3XjWrXX3K8x2MHryuClxIXf0Zvhxh@fAtoryP3phuH0cvoQGpIZ0/JAE1oN0Qt1lsHBZ73xtu4PqAIKTXE2DN/zHlrfGLRsaQTz99@xvR11x5og47e2ILoEC/JNjiiI0BldhwJvJsOzp4FQ3lgOrLs9Qsrav2xuP@Es8WKlscm6E8zA6@@M1yYwQXRm42A7MzeOoeS/zQ5zaVQXx1q@cuG4G/mvNqB5iOJZaIfZ3VsIddRdHO8/iHjs04VFTl1V3//ywbmo7t/g@FaE0XCOioMtmdkCDQgQOKodrUaHayxwovehg@KLQEO8xzd5kNoFrP3ha6yVsWykXnJ55R4qBy8ue5B1aSe561i9Nlbrs6cr1L1O3A@2vnmq@vH@7gMhnkain6q9kccsybJJh5WA@3nsPM03cXzEe/Ng@a9Fe6szcnN8D377IljkECCesbv/FxA1AQxpPRmm718EJjgtPC9CUuHJ4ExfBBzRfnpecKTCk8H540XAqasvzwuOVHgyOK9fpqyq7JnLChWeAE5/6jF8jwde46@cS4sxOni@u@ydaHjVID6hw891mDXAuTKcamCpNI@Co53ThzHBG19oCHPUuCX2hPYvQr3xijdU2TdQCefJ8JbbzSDKzJ0IOxeF4ehY4SCvqSNvBH2pRtBmqAz5yzIcQ4tX6k6rV36qOKdpQ1qRbCmOncllXiTba3Ipqpan9Jqs1Q@5d/OxRMM0y5K8Z82OcjLNcV45TWf4i5UZSyEPBGl2SWPlMEESuB0VlDQV@UShMJOM4Pe3iZ7QTtNDez/xhJXbqsjlyLaT0ZYznJPL8fpcj8TvmbxQjG6RT4/e8UuI9kNT8GsHQqa48EWVj13EiNhVbZGhCjCGKq0Mf4Mx6EY3o1dipWokl8kt6lBUHVX9/XDGBHJEHZsu4S8AIn7ZgrgqUSQBDSbhOqvzGSLWXZXUBwtHt2062oMPiOlrNZTOIUuzV2it0a1rtANLFqvFIj2ABfiPYAT87xnVmdRLQkwenYRa/ePj4zR9zIrzt@fT6/WbzXVxIf9Ppo@L84t37y4Wi/8A)

Figured nobody else is likely to post a braingolf answer, so here's mine.
Takes input as an integer, Prints a positive number for truthy, and a negative number or zero for falsey

Explanation:

```
dl2/2->[+]>l3->[+],-
d                     Split last item on stack into digits, push each digit to stack
 l                    Push length of stack to stack
  2/                  Halve last item on stack
    2-                Subtract 2 from last item on stack
      >               Move last item on stack to start of stack
       [+]            Sum last 2 items of stack 3 times (last 4 items)
          >           Move last item on stack to start of stack
           l          Push length of stack to stack
            3-        Subtract 3 from last item on stack
              [+]     Sum last 2 items of stack 3 times (last 4 items)
                 ,-   Subtract last item (sum of first half) from 2nd to last (sum of 2nd half)
                      Implicit: Print last item on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

I think it might be too early in the morning for golf; this seems much longer than it needs to be!

Takes input as an array of individual digits.

```js
n=>(g=(a,b)=>eval(n.slice(a,b).join`+`))(0,l=n.length/2)>g(l,l+l)
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
n=>(g=(a,b)=>eval(n.slice(a,b).join`+`))(0,l=n.length/2)>g(l,l+l)
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])) // false
console.log(f([8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])) // true
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1])) // false
console.log(f([1,2])) // false
console.log(f([2,1,4,7,5,8,3,9,2,6,3,9,5,4,3,3,8,5])) // false
console.log(f([1,0,0,1])) // false
console.log(f([1,0,0,0,0,0])) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 122 bytes

```
@set/al=r=0
@set/ps=
:l
@set/al+=%s:~,1%,r+=%s:~-1%
@set s=%s:~1,-1%
@if not "%s%"=="" goto l
@if %l% gtr %r% echo 1
```

Takes input on STDIN and outputs `1` if the value is significant.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

```java
boolean f(long n){int x=10,a=x,s=0;for(;a<n;n/=x,a*=x)s+=n%x;for(;n>0;n/=x)s-=n%x;return s<0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#ZU/LboMwEDzjr/Clkt2mLm@ICP2CtheOVQ8ONcSVs0bYJFQo307tJLfuSuvVjGdGO0x7JVvcKm4MfucSlnWvtRIccEeUhh4DXSRYPNdRuOH1vDF1WHV6JBXfQQUvDuGP9UzNUw0P842B1/DKUPN8BUdhpxGw2YXVZR1uicZy656Tlt/46HJJY0cJ/ecX5mNv6IKCH37ibLJSsablAGLEpsU1BnHG/yjS/BorjkwCrVBwPkgliGnZgZsPMds3CYJQ7xnc/@nJssHlWQXEG/rLCWWdF4FXuMudwptdkOs1ipM0y4sSlUWepUkcIY/cFxRHaZGVyTbOk61jkzJDURhGfrj6Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>29</s> 17 bytes

*Saved 12 bytes thanks to ETHproductions and obarakon*

```
¯½*Ul)x >Us½*Ul)x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39o/aG9WqE5mhUKdqHFUOb//9GGOmY6xjrmsQA)

Comment: Nice answer! The input can be an array, so you can do something like `A=Ul /2U¯A x >UtA x`

Comment: `¯½*Ul)x >UsUl /2 x` for 18 bytes!

Comment: @obarakon And another byte off that: `¯½*Ul)x >Us½*Ul)x` (It brings a tear of joy to my eye to see someone other than myself helping someone else golf in Japt, haha)

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh, I didn't think `s½` would work. Sweet!

Comment: @obarakon It's a bug in the current version of the online interpreter, but not in TIO. I'll push a fix in a couple minutes...

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```hs
f s=sum s<2*sum(take(div(length s)2)s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bU3NDsIgDL77FD14ANODgAxM3JMQDiTblCi4CPr62GzReLBN@jXfT9smKH15JignuSNkNVxHNsQXu435XC9QuOSFtxRihh6G@wao5kfMFbaQwgwTOGfRYIcaD6hQovDoBO4/7f3fjCCnooSmpEG7ZFbm94qkSTtxhpyWlCNp3YLrP0Ws/n4U3rc3) Takes the integer as list of digits and returns either `True` or `False`. Example usage: `f [1,2,3,4]`.

```hs
f s=                                   -- function f takes a list s
    sum s                              -- return whether the sum of s
         <2*sum(                     ) -- is smaller than two times the sum of
                take(div(length s)2)s  -- the first (length s/2) elements of s
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @nimi for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 36 Bytes

```
#>#2&@@BlockMap[Total,#,Length@#/2]&
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 65 bytes

`s=...load("x="..s:gsub(".","+%0"):gsub("+","-",#s/2))()print(x<0)`

Steps of conversion:

```
1234
+1+2+3+4
-1-2+3+4
x=-1-2+3+4
eval the last string
print(x<0)
```

Usage:

```
$ lua program.lua 1234
false
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>13</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-4 bytes by making tacit

```
>/+/0N 2#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUrLCYAwFLs7RamHKqJ9n/4FR3CMXnpwA1evLYoJJCFJWa9Sa06HXrQiAedYQaCAj3hntSWlJonExjof5C6Dd9YwYYu9/WMTQuNt4EiOY/twsH0BwNca5DzUBw)

Takes a list of integers as the input.

- `0N 2#` split input into pairs
- `+/` sum the pairs column-wise
- `>/` is the sum of the first chunk larger than the sum of the second?

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 20 bytes

```
[ halves v- Σ 0 > ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/NCoJQEIX3PsV5gSTzJytoG23aRKtocblNKOrVrlchxKfpfXql26gQhAzMzzfnDMxDSFNqezkfT4ctano2pCTVKIRJxuS2NCgm4jYqleWdUGky5lXpVBlkpBXl2DmdA3TwsIKPACEirBGjH2nMfcQs4N2KNf2fdk6nbmABO0P2@9jwHI11uuMzDWceD8tf9E5vr0hE3vJL7QKfN8M9brYQFWojZObaLw)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a sequence of integers from the data stack as input and leaves a boolean value on the data stack as output. Assuming `{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 }` is on top of the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `halves` Split a sequence in half.

  **Stack:** `{ 1 2 3 4 } { 5 6 7 8 }`
- `v-` Element-wise subtraction of two vectors. (This is shorter than summing each sequence individually.)

  **Stack:** `{ -4 -4 -4 -4 }`
- `Σ` Sum.

  **Stack:** `-16`
- `0 >` Is it greater than zero?

  **Stack:** `f`

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
2ẆʂØv
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPWQmY29kZT0yJUUxJUJBJTg2JUNBJTgyJUMzJTk4diZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEyMzQ1Njc4JTIwLSUzRSUyMEZhbHNlJTBBODc2NTQzMjElMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTEyMzQ0MzIxJTIwLSUzRSUyMEZhbHNlJTBBMTIlMjAtJTNFJTIwRmFsc2UlMEEyMTQ3NTgzOTI2Mzk1NDMzODUlMjAtJTNFJTIwRmFsc2UlMEExMDAxJTIwLSUzRSUyMEZhbHNlJTBBMTAwMDAwJTIwLSUzRSUyMFRydWUmZmxhZ3M9Qw==)

##### Explanation

```python
2ẆʂØv  # Implicit input
2Ẇ     # Split into 2 pieces
  ʂ    # Sum each inner list
   Øv  # Strictly decreasing?
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```ruby
->(x){n=x.length/2;c=x.codepoints;c[0,n].sum>c[n,n].sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmCrEPNf106jQrM6z7ZCLyc1L70kQ9/IOhnISc5PSS3Iz8wrKbZOjjbQyYvVKy7NtUuOzoMya/9XALWnp5YU6yVn5OcWcBWUlhQrpOklJ@bkKFT8NzI0MTe1MLY0MjO2NDUxNrYwBQA)

This works with a string of digit characters via *gets*.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 29 bytes

```arturo
$=>[0a:0loop&[x,y][y+'a+x]a>]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?l9RoHk)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
>.*msdc2Q
```

Takes an array of integers.

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3E.%2amsdc2Q&input=%5B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%0A%5B8%2C7%2C6%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B2%2C1%2C4%2C7%2C5%2C8%2C3%2C9%2C2%2C6%2C3%2C9%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C3%2C8%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D&debug=0)

Comment: [Golfed](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3EFsMc2Q&input=%5B4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%0A%5B8%2C7%2C6%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B2%2C1%2C4%2C7%2C5%2C8%2C3%2C9%2C2%2C6%2C3%2C9%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C3%2C8%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 98 bytes

```
(()){{}({}<>)([][<>[]])}{}({{}})<>({{}}<>[{}()])([({}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#HYyxDcAwCATXgSJFTJzYksUiFkXmeDE7gVSI444gYgac4EuZtu2l24y9ENx56T@TJmFLpdSqlI2yYVBdUswGRAuutWVUP@ER7byePmS2W2a/REaP4/0A)

```
#Push half of the input onto the alternate stack in reverse
(()){{}({}<>)([][<>[]])}{}

#Sum the main stack
({{}})<>

#Sum the alternate stack and subtract the sum of the main stack +1 from it
({{}}<>[{}()])

#Greater than or equal to 0?
([({}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}
```

Credit to [Wheat Wizard, Riley, and MegaTom for collaboratively coming up with that *greater than 0* snippet in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37121743#37121743)

Comment: It's a bit sad how half of the code is >=0.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 12 bytes

```
l~_,2//::+~>
```

Explanation:

```
l~  e# Read line and evaluate:   | [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
_,  e# Duplicate and get length: | [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 8
2/  e# Divide by 2:              | [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 4
/   e# Break into groups:        | [[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8]]
::+ e# Sum each:                 | [10 26]
~   e# Unpack:                   | 10 26
>   e# More than:                | 0 (false)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 44 bytes

```
#(neg?(apply +(map -(drop(/(count %)2)%)%)))
```

Input is a sequence of ASCII integers. This ended up being a bit shorted than using `split-at`, and also avoids `for` as `map` stops when one of the input lists runs out. So this substracts element-wise the two halves of the input and checks if the sum of differences is negative or not (as we are substracting the second half from the first).

```
(def f #(neg?(apply +(map -(drop(/(count %)2)%)%))))
(f (map int "214758392639543385"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
n=[int(i) for i in list(input())];sum(n[:len(n)//2])*2>sum(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P882OjOvRCNTUyEtv0ghUyEzTyEnsxgokFdQWqKhqRlrXVyaq5EXbZWTmqeRp6mvbxSrqWVkBxbU/P/f0MjYxNQMAA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for ways you can golf your program. This currently doesn't output anything, as it doesn't have a `print(...)` around the comparison. Alternatively, you can change it to a function that returns its result. Right now, this is just a snippet

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 39 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.875 bytes

```
½EṠƒ<
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiwr1F4bmgxpI8IiwiIiwiXCIxMjM0NTY3OFwiIl0=)

### Explained

```
½EṠƒ<­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
½E     # ‎⁡Push the input string into two halves and evaluate each
  Ṡ    # ‎⁢Vectorised sums
   ƒ<  # ‎⁣Reduce by less than.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

Sadly, this solution is **1** byte longer than the shortest JS answer!
As allowed by OP, it takes an array of single-digit integers as input.

```javascript
t=>t.map((e,i)=>t[i*2]+1?a+=e:b+=e,a=b=0)|a>b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BTsMwEEX3PYXllY2HKEnbNFRye5CqUp3UqVKFOIodxIItOyQuAAfgWrlImMZUgCjVSLY8//0/nqN6UDZvy8bd1mavh0IOTq5ccK8axjSUHB@b8ibeimithNTLDA9QMpMhf1KrbFDW6tZJVtZN50A/Njp3eg@ttl3lZOH7HGNyU1tT6aAyB8a@ZHnm17R/eyZ0Sfv3F0K5GF3B0ZT1bico6V8/CBXexCcTP5ORTQQxTGEGc0hgAemWAClUZTXh30yKSoLEDMkYohPj2u4Xco75gfyJQeZiH3n0LXBAiu479Cfj7QdOsTv/Jy/Eiq5oY1367mnf0G/rpeET)

---

`a` and `b` store the sum of the digits of the first and second half of the parameter, respectively.

We use `t[i*2]+1` to check in which half of the array we are. The `+1` is mandatory because the input array can contain zeroes, which would lead to a wrong answer in particular test cases like `4508 -> true`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <s>61</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/96039/)!*

Takes an array of digits as input.

```
a=A.length/2
f(A)=\{\sum_{n=1}^a(A[n]-A[n+a])>0\}
```

*(if you paste this into your own graph paste it line-by-line and while pasting \$f(A)\$ into Desmos add a newline in front - the Desmos parser is kind of bugged in that respect)*

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o5hinrupum?nographpaper)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 61 bytes

Takes the input as an array of base 10 digits, splits it in half, and then checks if sums of the halves are in order.

```
|s|!s.chunks(s.len()/2).map(|c|u8::sum(c.iter())).is_sorted()
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%23%21%5Bfeature%28is_sorted%29%5D%0A%0Ause+std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3ASum%3B%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++fn+parse_input%28string%3A+%26%27static+str%29+-%3E+Vec%3Cu8%3E+%7B%0A++++++++string%0A++++++++++++.chars%28%29%0A++++++++++++.map%28%7Cc%7C+c.to_digit%2810%29.unwrap%28%29+as+u8%29%0A++++++++++++.collect%28%29%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++let+solution%3A+fn%28%26%5Bu8%5D%29+-%3E+bool+%3D%0A++++++++%7Cs%7C+%21s.chunks%28s.len%28%29+%2F+2%29.map%28%7Cc%7C+u8%3A%3Asum%28c.iter%28%29%29%29.is_sorted%28%29%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+%7Cs%7C%21s.chunks%28s.len%28%29%2F2%29.map%28%7Cc%7Cu8%3A%3Asum%28c.iter%28%29%29%29.is_sorted%28%29%0A%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26parse_input%28%2212345678%22%29%29%2C+false%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26parse_input%28%2287654321%22%29%29%2C+true%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26parse_input%28%2212%22%29%29%2C+false%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26parse_input%28%22214758392639543385%22%29%29%2C+false%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26parse_input%28%221001%22%29%29%2C+false%29%3B%0A++++assert_eq%21%28solution%28%26parse_input%28%22100000%22%29%29%2C+true%29%3B%0A%7D%0A)